# Protect routes in react with server side rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have a react app and I serving it with Node js. I currently have a jwt token implemented in node js. So, when I login a token is sent back to the client and then stored in localstorage.

To verify that the user is logged in and has rights to access some of the pages. I will need to

1. Get the token from local storage
2. Check the expiry of the token. And if it is expired redirect them back to the login page.

I currently cannot get passed the 1st step

Here is what I have

private-route.js

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {

const [token, setToken] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    setToken(localStorage.getItem("usr-sess"));
    console.log(token);
}, [token]);
return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        token ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        )
      }
    />
 );
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

app.js

```
  <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/login" component={LoadableLogin} />
     <PrivateRoute eexact path="/test" component={LoadableTestPage} />
     <Route component={LoadableNotFound} />
  </Switch>
```

server.tsx

```
const jsx = renderToString(
  <ApolloProvider client={clientConfig}>
    <Loadable.Capture report={moduleName => modules.push(moduleName)}>
      <StaticRouter context={context} location={req.url}>
        <App />
      </StaticRouter>
    </Loadable.Capture>
  </ApolloProvider>
);
```

I constantly keep being redirected back to login even when the token is there.

The issue is that it takes a bit of time to setToken() and by then it will redirect me back to login. Is there any way to do this?

Not using useEffect and doing

```
 localStorage.getItem("usr-sess") ? (
     <Component {...props} />
   ) : (
     <Redirect to="/login" />
   )
```

throws a localStorage undefined error, I can't think of anything else to do.